# What is the current legal status of living human clones?

Tags: united-states, human-rights, citizenship, hypothetical

What are the current laws on the books regarding complete or incomplete clones of humans? With or without natural birth? What is their legal status as individuals, and do they have a right to citizenship?

This would be a product of illegal action, clearly, but the product could still exist.

Comment: Do you mean a close that starts out as a baby, like Dolly the sheep? Or a clone that becomes exactly as the cloned person was- 30 year old man and now there are two 30 year old men- like in a sci fi movie? If the former, what makes you think he/she would have a legal status unlike any other baby human, other than a complicated "who are the parents?" that already has been addressed by laws and court cases around surrogacy?

Comment: @Damila The former, mostly. Do they have a claim to citizenship without parents? Could they be mass produced for slavery, as a bred product? Kind of in a "cruelty free meat" sense?

Comment: Before or after they are decanted from a Tube?

Answer (score 1):

### The same as it is for sentient aliens or plants

They don’t exist so they have no legal status. When they do exist, then the law will deal with them.

Comment: Humans already exist. Different types of IVF and surrogacy already exist. This answer ignores that when new things arise, the courts apply existing laws related to similar circumstances and legislatures make new laws especially if they don't like how the courts applied the existing laws.

Comment: @Damila which is what I said. When they exist, and there is a controversy, the courts will deal with it.